# How to define the degrees of freedom of a flexible manipulator?

Tags: manipulator

Consider a cable-driven flexible manipulator which has 3 cables. Consider the 3 cables to be actuated by 3 motors. Assume that by pulling the three cables in different configurations, we can span the entire 3D space in the workspace of the manipulator.

The manipulator is made up of a single flexible backbone and has disks mounted on it as shown in the figure..

I read on some sources as the manipulator is flexible it has infinite degrees of freedom. Is that correct?

**How to define the degrees of freedom of the manipulator in task space and in configuration space?**
[image: Here we can see 3 blue cables actuating section 2 and 3 yellow cable actuating section 1]

Comment: could you replace the space between any two disks with two servos in XY orientation and maintain functionality?

Comment: You have to keep in mind your system is actually a 2 stage system with independent control from each other...hence “section 1&2”

Comment: @jsotola i didn't understand what you meant by replace the space with servos in XY... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @morbo agreed. So what would be the degrees of freedom of each section?

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram has 6 cables and your question refers to 3 cables, so I'll just consider the simpler case.

1. The distal end (effector) moves in 3D space (a volume) - task space. Whilst the accessible space is limited, it does require 3 axes to describe its terminal point.
2. The input is 3 cables, so you only have 3 variables to play with to get a particular (accessible) distal end position. I suspect that is what you have called the configuration space. That looks like 3 dof to me.
3. The mapping of 3 inputs to 3 outputs is possible, and that transformation has no superfluous components (meaning you have enough, but not too much, information).
4. A little change to any input makes a little change to the output; there are no discontinuities in the transformation. In this sense, the manipulator can, theoretically, move infinitely small distances.

In a jointed manipulator (like an arm, with a hand), there can be lots of servos. However, at the end of the first finger, we still only need 3 numbers to describe its position in space, even if we chose to move 17 servos to get it there. Our 17-dof manipulator still only achieves the position in 3D, needing only 3 numbers to define its position.

(Note that we have ignored the orientation of the manipulated object. Yes, there's lots more to think about, yet.)

Comment: I agree that it has 3 controllable variables (length of control cables) and as long as it is a deterministic or linear system, this would mean it's a 3DOF system. The other 3 cables (tendon cables) are not controllable.